# Fetching data from table and display in Bootstrap modal to edit

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use Bootstrap modal for updating my data in database. But I'm getting an error
on my script in passing the data from my table to my modal. I use edit icon to triggered my modal to pop up but data from my table is not displaying.
this is my table:
[image: this is my table]
this is the error I get whenever I try to fetch the data from my table and display to my modal to edit:
[image: this is the error I get whenever I try to fetch the data from my table and display to my modal to edit]

```
    <div class="col-md-12  " style="margin-top: 3rem !important; padding-bottom:10rem;">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%; ">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <!-- <th>ID</th> -->
                <th>School Year</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Action</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <!-- <td>< ?  php echo $row['id']; ?></td> -->
                <td><?php echo $row['school_year']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                                             
                     if($row['status'] == 1)
                    {
                    echo "<button class='btn btn-success' style='width:6rem !important; font-size:13px'>Active</button>"; 
                    }
                    else{
                    echo "<button class='btn btn-primary' style='width:6rem !important; font-size:13px'>Inactive</button>";
                    }
                    ?>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <!-- THIS IS MY BUTTON FOR  BOOTSTRAP TO EDIT AND DELETE -->
                    <a style="padding:20px; color:green;"><i class="far fa-edit editbtn"></i></a>
                    <a style="color:darkred" data-href="../Actions/school_year_delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>" ;
                        data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php}} ?>
            </tfoot>
    </table>

</div>


<!-- Modal For Editing-->
<div class="modal fade" id="editmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">


            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit School Year</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <form action="school_year.php" method="POST">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="col-md-10 m-auto">
                        <br>
                        <label for="">School year</label>
                        <input type="text" name="year" id="year" class="form-control">
                        <label for="">Status</label>

                        <select type="number" name="status" id="status" class="form-control">
                            <option value="" selected disabled>--Select if default</option>
                            <option value=" 1 ">Active</option>
                            <option value="2">Inactive</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="add" value="name" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**THIS IS MY Script**

```
$('.editbtn').on('click', function() {
    $('#editmodal').modal('show');

    $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var data = $tr.children("td").map(function() {
        return $($this).text();
    }).get();
    
    console.log(data);
    $('#school_year').val(data[0]);
    $('#status').val(data[1]);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

since I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question, You give wrong id in bootstrap-modal :

```
 <label for="">School year</label>
                    <input type="text" name="year" id="school_year" class="form-control">
                    <label for="">Status</label>
```